# PDF output failure when knitting "greater than or equal to" symbol using RMarkdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pandoc

I am writing a R Mardown file where I want to show up some mathematical symbols in the PDF created by knitting the Rmd file. One of the symbols I am getting trouble with is greater or equal. This is my RMarkdown file:

```
---
title: "Módulo 3. Modelos lineales I. Introducción. Regresión simple y múltiple"
author: "Mario Modesto Mata"
date: "4 April 2018"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---


| Variables dependientes (*Y*) | Variables independentes (*X*) | Análisis |
| :------- | :------: | -----: |
| = 1 | = 1 continua    | Regresión simple| 
| = 1   | > 1 continuas     | Regresión múltiple| 
| > 1   | $\geq$ 1 continuas    | Regresión múltiple multivariada| 
| = 1   | = 1 discretas     | ANOVA unifactorial| 
| = 1   | > 1 discretas     | ANOVA multifactorial| 
| > 1   | $\geq$ 1 discretas    | MANOVA (ANOVA multivariado)| 
| = 1   | $\geq$ 1 continuas & $\geq$ 1 discretas   | ANCOVA|
```

I tried using the LaTex codes `$\geq$` and `\geq` with no success. Also with the HTML code `&ge;`. However, none of these works when creating a PDF, as I am always getting an error like this one:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ≥ (U+2265)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Any idea?

Comment: What pandoc and LaTeX versions are you using?

Comment: @mb21 I use pandoc 2.3.1

Comment: This compiles without problem when I knit it in RStudio. I saved the file using a UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Same here, it compiles fine. Probably a LaTeX font issue. Can you add the full pandoc command that R Markdown produces and maybe try with an alternative pdf engine (xelatex or luatex)?

Comment: This is late to the game for this answer, but I had a similar issue knitting to PDF that was solved by escaping the slash.  I was trying to make it work from within a code block, and was getting "\g is an unrecognized escape..."   The code that worked for me was  `$\\geq$`